# python fnmatch exclude path with string

Tags: python, fnmatch

I want to perform check and allow access to only specific pattern URLs and exclude few.

Using the following check to match for the allowed URLs

```py
ALLOWED_URL = [
  '/auth/*'
]
```

and using `fnmatch` to match the pattern

```
any(fnmatch(request.path, p) for p in settings.ALLOWED_URL)
```

This works for the following URL

- `/auth/login/`
- `/auth/signup/google/`
- `/auth/user-tracking/`

But I want to exclude `/auth/user-tracking/` from the URL and user should not access it. So I modified the pattern as

```py
MULTI_USER_EXCLUDE_PATH = [
    '/auth/[!user-tracking/*]*'
]
```

But this is now not working for

- `/auth/signup/google/`

Comment: Is it OK to define a new `EXCLUDED_URL` list?

Comment: `[!user-tracking/*]` does not exclude "user-tracking/*" it excludes **any character** in that sequence and `s` is in that sequence

Comment: @AboAmmar Yes it is okay to dfine a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new `EXCLUDED_URL` list . Then, use the `check_url_access` function to check if the request path starts with any of the paths in `EXCLUDED_URL` list. If it does, the function returns `False` to indicate that access is denied.

```
import fnmatch

EXCLUDED_URL = [
    '/auth/user-tracking/'
]

ALLOWED_URL = [
  '/auth/*'
]

def check_url_access(request):
    if any(request.path.startswith(p) for p in EXCLUDED_URL):
        return False
    return any(fnmatch.fnmatch(request.path, p) for p in ALLOWED_URL)

# Let's check google, for example:
request = type("Request", (object,), {"path": "/auth/signup/google/"})
if check_url_access(request):
    print("Access allowed")
else:
    print("Access denied")
```

```
Access allowed
```